# Confusion about relationship between energy per coulomb, and the amount of coulombs in current

Tags: voltage, current, charge

I am trying to understand how a power supply works and working from the ground up I am learning about electricity, voltage, current, amps, and wattage. I am new to this stuff so I apologize if this is an easy or already answered question.

From what I have read so far, here is my understanding:

- electricity in a current is the movement of free electrons through a conductive material. The free
  electrons "hop" from one atom to the next.
- a coulomb is a unit of charge.
- Charge by itself is just a property of an object, number of electrons or lack thereof. When charges are separated, they create an electric field, which then allows you to define potential energy that an object in the field would have, depending on its location in that field, regardless of its charge. The potential energy is the Joules/Coloumb at that specific point in the e-field, which is volts. If you take volts * charge of object in the field at that point, you get the electric potential energy that the charge would carry.
- That electric potential energy is converted to some other energy for useful work as the charge moves through the current - light, heat, or power for a component. This is analogous to how potential energy of a falling object in a gravitational field is converted to kinetic energy.
- The AMOUNT of charge, moving past a specific point, is the Amperes. This is a rate measurement in coulomb's per second.
- Voltage and Amps are directly proportional. If you take voltage, which is joules per coulomb, and you take amps, which is coloumbs / s, and you multiply them, you get joules / s. This intuitively to me, means the amount of energy that can be provided to some component in a circuit, per second. This is Watts.

My confusion is that I don't understand the relationship between "amount of charge" and "energy of charge". A common analogy used here is water and water pressure. If I have a tank filled with water, and I attach a hose at the bottom, and I apply X amount of pressure, a certain amount of water (measured volume of water) will move past a certain point in the hose at a rate of Y. If I increase X, then the water molecules move more quickly through the hose, meaning numerically more water molecules move past the certain point, so Y (flow rate volume / second) increases. So, more pressure causes water molecules to move faster, meaning more water gets through the hose - i.e more volume of water per second.

With voltage and charges, voltage is supposed to represent pressure. If I increase the voltage, the numerically more electrons - more units of charge - flow through the circuit. But due to what? In other words, my question is:

Which of the following is correct?

1. **More couloumbs AND more energy per coulomb**: When voltage increases, amount of energy per unit of charge increases. This means each unit of charge is more "energized", and BECAUSE of that, moves faster through the circuit. Faster charges means MORE charges move through the circuit per second, and because each charge is MORE energized, there is more joules per second at any given point in the circuit (more work).
2. **More coulombs BUT same energy per coulomb**: When voltage increases, more units of charge flow through the circuit. But each unit of charge still has the same amount of energy as before the voltage increase. The increase in potential energy is spread across more coulombs of charge.
3. **Same number of coulombs BUT more energy per coulomb**: When voltage increases, the number of coulombs flowing through the circuit remains the same, but the energy per coulomb increases.

I know 3 will not be true because of V = IR, but I want to understand this on an intuitive level. Does the increase in voltage equate to increase in energy per unit of charge, or does an increase in voltage keep energy per charge equal but forces more charges to flow through the circuit?

Comment: Thinking about it further, I think the answer is 1. Given a certain voltage, n electrons are displaced, and each of those electrons moves at a certain speed through the circuit. When the voltage increases, the pressure increases. If there was only 1 free electron, it would move faster, have higher speed. With n electrons, all n electrons move faster. If all electrons are moving faster, then there is higher throughput of electrons, more electrons moving past a point per second. Thus, current increases. Furthermore, for an electron to move "faster", it probably needs to be more "energized".

Comment: "Voltage and Amps are directly proportional." No, not always. This is true for resistors, and the constant of proportionality is the **resistance**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> electricity in a current is the movement of free electrons through a conductive material.

This is one kind of current. But it's also possible to have positive current carriers. Batteries and many kinds of transistors would not work if electrons were the only kind of current carrier.

> Voltage and Amps are directly proportional.

This is true in a linearly resistive material. For example in a copper wire or a resistor.

In other components, there will be a different relationship. For example, in a (junction) diode the current goes up exponentially with increased voltage across the device. In a transistor the current through one branch of the device may depend on the voltage across a different branch of the device.

> Which of the following is correct?

Again, it depends what kind of device you are investigating.

> More couloumbs AND more energy per coulomb:

This is the behavior of a resistor. If you increase the voltage across the resistor, by definition, you've increased the energy per coulomb lost as charge flows through the device. And, because of the nature of the resistor, you will also increase the current (rate of charge flowing through).

> More coulombs BUT same energy per coulomb:

This would be the behavior of a voltage source when you change its load. You can increase or decrease the current you draw from it, but it will always (to the extent it's an *ideal* voltage source) produce the same potential across its terminals.

> Same number of coulombs BUT more energy per coulomb

This is the behavior of a current source. You can apply whatever potential you want across it, and it will always (again, in the ideal case) produce the same current.

Comment: Wait, i thought conventional current was just a convention. So there are actual positive charge carriers through a battery?

Comment: There are positive carriers in batteries, other ionic conductors, plasmas, p-type semiconductors, ...

Comment: Ok, to be honest this is still over my head. If I plug a device like a powersupply into a wall outlet of 110V, the power supply will receive some current. If I plug the same power supply into a wall with 220V, will I get more coulombs but same energy per coulomb since its a voltage source with a new load?

Comment: You will get a higher potential (220 V instead of 110 V). Whether it draws more current depends on the load. A resistive load will draw more current. A device (a computer or a phone charger, for example) with a switching power supply will draw less current.

Comment: My main point is that whether a device draws more, less, or the same current depends on the design of that device. There is no universal law of nature that says it is always more.

Comment: I see, a power supply will draw the current it needs to, probably based on voltage. In that case it might be that an increase in voltage translates to a decrease in current, in order to have the same power output. in a more basic case however, like a battery attached to a plain copper wire, what happens? If I have a copper wire attached to a 10V battery, and a different copper wire attached to a 20V battery, and these are 2 separate systems, would the 20V system have higher current AND more energy per coulomb?

Comment: A copper wire is a resistor (although it has very low resistance). Yes, if you short a 20-V supply with a wire it will deliver higher current (at higher voltage) than if you short a 10 V supply. That's why the power consumed by the resistor comes out to \$V^2/R\$.

Comment: Ok cool, so based on your answer copper wire should have more energy per coulomb AND more coulombs flowing through. Kind of like increasing the pressure in a water tank, more water flows through and each unit of water flows faster. 

Thanks for your help! Hopefully I understood it properly, I thought I was going crazy when I was getting confused about this and didn't see anybody else ask the same question lol.

Comment: One more thing if you have the time, is my understanding of the power supply correct as a device in this case correct? If a power supply is rated for W watts, then when it's connected to a V volt plug, it will draw I current. So if V increases, the energy per coulomb increases by definition, but since a PS is not like a resistor, it will limit the current that comes through it. By increasing V and decreasing I, W stays the same. Is that accurate? I'm disregarding AC/DC because I haven't read about that yet.

Comment: It will depend what load is connected to the output of the power supplpy.

Comment: @JeremyFisher - most of these comments and answers you’re responding to aren’t well informed. A switching power supply that can operate from either 110vac or 220vac typically uses a circuit that automatically selects how the input power is rectified to create unregulated ~300v DC power. The rest of the power supply is designed to convert the unregulated 300vdc to the desired output voltages. Transformer input linear power supplies have a switch to put the input windings in parallel or in series. Aside from inefficiently differences, the input current at 220v is half the input current at 110v.

Comment: @OliverStreet, you're claiming what? There are no positive charge carriers? There are no negative-resistance loads? If there's something you think is wrong in this answer or my comments please be specific what that is. If you want to provide a better answer, just do that.

Comment: @ThePhoton - yes. To both.In solid state semiconductors, positive charge carriers are an intellectual construct. The protons are immobile, the hoke drift rate is not the drift rate of protons or atoms that are electron-deprived. What’s moving is which atom is electron deprived. The rate at which atom diffuse in a solid state semiconductor crystal is so slow it’s irrelevant to the hole drift velocity. 
   Negative

Comment: @ThePhoton - Negative resistance is a transient effect literally due to momentum. It is only found when the potential is reversed as a cloud of traveling charges arrives. The derivative of the voltage to current ratio dv/di is negative but to understand it as negative resistance is a misattibution. Negative resistance is most often attributed to Gunn, Impatt and other P-I-N junctions, Corona discharge, and it’s vacuum only cousin multipaction. The structures all have a drift region. Real stuff is more interesting than the urban legends, even though there’s no free energy.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I should clarify that a proton is a positive charge carrier and does exist, it’s just immobile in solids and that’s where the positive charge carrier is a misattribution. The hard way to get them is as ionized gas, it takes a lot of energy to move the electron far away. The easy way is leave it nearby - as an ionically bound molecule in solution. They physically drift in an electrolyte by swapping pairings, and it’s why hydrogen collects at the terminal of a lead-acid battery being charged as lonely drifting protons finally gets electrons they don’t have to share.

Comment: @OliverStreet, those are pretty subtle distinctions that we could argue about all day (like is an electron hole "really real"?), but they're not really relevant to the misunderstanding that motivated OP's question.